# How to tell resharper to execute tests on moved assemblies?

Tags: unit-testing, resharper

We just modularized our "monolithic" solution into three solutions called `framework`, `plugin1` and `plugin2`. Each solution produces dlls in a dedicated folder called `dist_framework`, `dist_plugin1` and `dist_plugin2`, which contain only their respective dlls. In a *post-build* step, we copy all these dlls in a shared folder called `dev_dist`, where the application can be executed. **NUnit** can run the tests in this folder. Unfortunately, **resharper** executes by default tests in the *project output* folders, namely `dist_framework`, `dist_plugin1` and `dist_plugin2`, but `dist_plugin1` and `dist_plugin2`don't contain all dependencies and the test-execution fails.

Is there any way to tell resharper to execute the tests in dlls located in another folder?

Than you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper will only run tests on the code in your solution. After all, if a test in a pre-compiled assembly fails, how do you fix it?